# Inappropriate to include source code from a documented link?

Tags: support, specific-answer

It took me a while to track down a version of code which was actually in compliance with an error I was experiencing. A post on SO helped me figure out which one to look for.

Once found, I decided to post an answer with the findings, and a link to the publicly shared code.

However, I know that links can degrade over time and thought that perhaps I should also include the code that was at the link. It has a license which I also included. The source is verbatim.

Was it inappropriate to include this code?

The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26004722/1026459

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this. You've given attribution, and you've even included the original license. You're good.

Comment: You cannot re-license that software to cc-by-sa, it is not your code and the Microsoft license doesn't allow it.  Instead of copy/pasting, you'll do SO users a much bigger favor by explaining what that validator actually does so other programmers can fall in the pit of success writing their own.  Technically that is not quite okay either but it is a lot less fuddy.

Comment: @Hans - I am not sure explaining the entirety of what the unobstrusive validator does is in the scope of that question, but I have removed the script.

Comment: Tough to find that kind of inspiration on a 1.5 year old question, yes.  I sympathize.  Your answer will be very useful to the next hundred programmers that google it anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) explicitly says

> Do not copy the complete text of external sources

So based on that guidance you shouldn't.

Additionally the Microsoft license that you pasted didn't indicate that they were OK with much else than using the code as part of a product.

If the link was to rot you have a handy copy in the revision history though!